# Coefficient of $x^n$ in $x \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{d} (x - i) (x + i)$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I am looking for a general form of the coefficient of $x^n$ in $x \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{d} (x - i) (x + i)$.  I know that the leading coefficient (in front of $x^{2 d + 1}$) is $1$, and there are no even powers of $x$, so I'm practically looking for the rest.

[Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) did not help me arrive at a closed form.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well at least if $n$ is even it's easy.

Comment: Those are related to so-called *central factorial numbers*. [OEIS links](http://oeis.org/search?q=central+factorial). The first kind $t(n,k)$ gives the coefficient of $x^k$ in a central factorial $x^{[n]}$, the second kind $T(n,k)$ gives the coefficient of $x^{[k]}$ in $x^n$. What you look for seems to be the first kind $t(2n,2k)$. Caution: The underlying definition of central factorial is a bit weird.

Comment: @ccorn: Interesting.  Thanks a lot!